# TypeKit rendering vs "regular font" rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts

We've used typekit during a beta period to use Proxima Nova as the font on our site.

Since Typekit will be a bit to expensive for us since we have a lot of page views we decided to buy our font from Myfonts and load it via their system.

Everything went well on the Mac and it looks more or less exactly the same with our new fonts from Myfonts as it did via Typekit.

But on Windows (all browsers i have tested) it looks pretty different. The font looks like it has less height and various other small differences. I know there is loads of post why fonts are rendering differently on Mac and PC but the thing here is that it seems like TypeKit has managed to work around that?

Anyone know if Typekit are doing any magic in their javascript to make the font look exactly the same in all browsers and in that case what is that?

You can take a look at http://beta.alternativeto.net/fonttest.html (alt2/beta2015 to login)

It's mainly the top menu you can see a major difference, if you have access to a Mac and a Windows PC you can also see lots of differences on the regular site. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: include Screenshots

Comment: It's likely they optimized the font files themselves.